# how To configure ffmpeg for the iPhone 4s and iphone5

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg

i want to configure ffmpeg,i have read https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor ,but this link only configure ffmpeg for the iPhone 3gs and iPod touch 3g using armv7 and iPhoneOS3.0.sdk, i want to configure ffmpeg for the iPhone 4s and iphone5 using armv7s and iPhone5.0sdk. can you give some advice and some link to finish it?

Comment: http://hunterford.me/compiling-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/  and  http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide

Comment: armv7 is fine for working on iPhone 4s and 5, until ffmpeg is optimized for armv7s if ever, there is no real benefit. I have successfully built and deployed versions up to 1.1 but these also do not have the armv7s arch.